# Why is this subset closed

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I try to understand the following statement:

Let $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ denote the vector space of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Now the statement is that the set

$S := \{\phi \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m-k})~|~ \text{rank}(\phi)<m-k \}$ is a closed subset in $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m-k})$.

Can anyone tell me why that is? Thanks!

Comment: What's the topology?

Comment: @5xum probably the topology will be the defined by the supremum norm.

Comment: @Masacroso Possibly, but let's let OP explain.

Comment: Actually it doesn't say something about the topology so I guess it is the most standard topology. The only topology mentioned is the Whitney topology for $C^{\infty}$ maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint.  Consider the special case $m=n$ and $k=0$.  Then $S$ consists of square matrices with rank less than $n$.  This is the same as the set of matrices with zero determinant.  Since the determinant is a continuous function on $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ (I assume this is true in your chosen topology), and $S$ is the inverse image of the point $0$, then $S$ is closed.

Now in general, you can still use the determinant, or many determinants, to determine rank.

Comment: The problem is that there is no word in the proof about the topology on $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$. Could you tell me a book where to find something something about this?

Comment: @JDoe: It's "probably" obvious in the context of this problem that the intended topology is the subspace topology inherited from $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{nm}$, with its Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 1):

Its complement is the set of all invertible linear maps. There's a general fact:

> For any Banach spaces $E$ and $F$, the set of invertible linear maps $E \to F$ is open in $\mathcal L(E,F)$ for the topology of $\|\cdot\|_{op}$.

Where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is the operator norm.

To prove this, you need Von Neumann's lemma. It's explained [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) how that is done.

Comment: So the set $S$ I described is then the complement of the set of invertible maps $E \to F$ in $L(E,F)$. And then the closeness follows from your fact. Correct?

Comment: @JDoe exactly. ${}$